# Positioning a timer created textarea ,that repeats on a timer , in a javascript coded tabs in a formatted website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website (html/css/javascript/php) on a WAMP server. The format is header. nav (on the left), section (to the right of the nav div). In the section I have a javascript 3 tabs container. I am pulling the info from a .php file and displaying the retrieved data in the textarea. The textarea is on a timer so each time new data is retrieved, a new textarea is created below the current textarea with the new data.

My problem, since Javascript is loaded into the page last, the textareas are positioned outside of the tabbed div container and run across all boundaries and borders.

How can I position the newly created textareas so they will appear and stay inside the first tab? Here is the code I am using so far.  I have tried many solutions and none worked, even absolute positioning did not work.

```
<div id="section">

    <!-- these are the tags ID and the href links back to itself, the page does not navigate forward or backward-->
<ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#order">.........Orders Placed</a></li>
  <li><a href="#delivered">.......Delivered</a></li>
  <li><a href="#cancelled">.......Cancelled</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tabContent" id="order" style="max-height:800px;overflow-y:scroll;border:1px solid red;">
     <div>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
        var t = document.createTextNode("<?php include('NewIncomingOrders.php')?>");
        x.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(x);
        setTimeout(myFunction, 9000);
        }

    </script>

     </div>

</div>
```

and the css I have tried: more than on way here, and I could not get any of them to work. I have a button included in the code to start the timed function.

```
TEXTAREA{      
      width:80em;
      height:4em;
      border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
      position:static;
      left: 195px; 
      top: 1px;      
    }
```

OR THIS METHOD:

```
.section{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.tabContent{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
}
.tabContent textarea{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

If anyone has an idea how to position the textarea so that it stays within the tab, or hints on what direction to go, please let me know!
Here is a picture to let you know what I mean.

Tab_Not_Working:

[image]

Comment: you're appending your new `<textarea>` elements to `body`.  append them to your tab container instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I must be missing the correct expression. I have tried these:  document.order.appendChild(x);,    document,tabContent.order.appendChild(x); document.body.appendChild(x).tabContent.order;  document.body.tabContent.order.appendChild(x); and I cannot get any of these to work. I am coming close to the correct expression?

Comment: Thank You Dan O!  You put me on the right path!!  I finally got it to working!  You are a Genius Dan O!  This is how I finally got it working:  <script type="text/javascript" >
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
   var t = document.createTextNode("<?php include('NewIncomingOrders.php')?>");
   x.appendChild(t);
   
   document.getElementById("order").appendChild(x);
   setTimeout(myFunction, 9000);
   }

  </script>

Answer (score 0):

Dan O put me on the right path. I got it working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
   function myFunction() { 
     var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
     var t = document.createTextNode("<?php include('NewIncomingOrders.php')>"); 
     x.appendChild(t);
     document.getElementById("order").appendChild(x);
     setTimeout(myFunction, 9000);
   }
</script>
```